# Replacing empty objects in array with one object in Python

Tags: python, arrays

I have this array:

```
["first line","","second line","","","","","more text","","","","last line"]
```

Its hard to describe, so I'm just going to show, what output I want:

```
["first line","","second line","...","more text","...","last line"]
```

When there are 3 or more empty objects together in the array, these should be replaced with one "...". What is the easiest way, I can do this?

Comment: No, you do not have an array. You have a list of strings and you want to replace two or more consecutive empty strings with the string "...". If you cannot describe a problem, you cannot find a solution. Now, tell us what you attempted, and add your code to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) is a natural fit for this. Just make the tests what you want in the comprehension:

```
from itertools import groupby

l = ["first line","","second line","","","","","more text","","","","last line"]

['...' if k=='' and len(list(g)) >= 3 else k for k, g in groupby(l)]
# ['first line', '', 'second line', '...', 'more text', '...', 'last line']
```

**EDIT:**
The above is nice if nothing else is repeated, but it will collapse repeated elements you want to keep. Here's a slightly more complicated way, that avoids that:

```
from itertools import groupby

# we want both "first line" strings in the output
l = ["first line","first line", "","second line","","","","","more text","","","","last line"]

def removeEmpties(l):
    for k, g in groupby(l):
        group = list(g)
        if k == '' and len(group) >= 3:
            yield '...'
        else:
            yield from group

list(removeEmpties(l))
# ['first line', 'first line', '', 'second line', '...', 'more text', '...', 'last line']
```